# seeing a therapist

Tags: indefinite-article, numbers

1. They are both seeing a therapist.
2. They are seeing a therapist.

Do those necessarily mean that they are seeing the same therapist?

Could they be used if each of them is seeing a different therapist?

Comment: "Both" implies a connection between the people but it's not clear what the connection is. Maybe it is the fact that both have chosen to see (different) therapists at the same time (which is in some way unusual or noteworthy), maybe they are seeing the same one, maybe everyone else is seeing faith healers but those two decided to see a therapist instead.

Comment: a therapist is a generality.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement says that 'They are both seeing a therapist', but this does not necessarily mean that 'They are both seeing **the same** therapist'.

The second statement says that 'They are seeing a therapist', which means the multiple people visit the same therapist. This statement is actually the same as 'They are seeing a therapist **together**.'

Comment: Thank you Cheese Cake, I suppose "They are all seeing a therapist." would not necessarily mean that they are seeing the same one. Is that correct?

Comment: @azz Yes, so the sentence you just wrote is a variation of the first statement in the question, except that it is for more than 2 people instead of 2 people.

Comment: You could say 'they are both seeing therapists'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, and that will have the same meaning as the first statement.

Comment: 'they are both seeing therapists' makes it clear there is not just _one_ therapist involved, and we'd probably assume they were seeing one each. Your first statement is as Cheese Cake said.

Comment: I don't think "They are seeing a therapist" necessarily means they are seeing the same therapist. "They are riding a bicycle" or "They are taking a holiday" don't necessarily mean they're on the same bicycle or holiday, and the same principle applies - you can use either singular or plural in such cases.